# поле ввода под Share your result!

Tags: html, отступы

Не понимаю, что за отступ появляется в поле ввода под Share your result!
Помогите разобраться.

```html
<form action="formdata.php" name="FormName" method="POST" style="margin:0 auto;width: 550px;">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Personal Info</legend>
    <p><label> Enter your name (max. 10 symbols): <input type="text" name="userName" placeholder="username" size="30" maxlength="10"></label> </p>

    <p><label> Enter your pass (max. 10 symbols): <input type="password" name="userName" placeholder="password" size="30" maxlength="10"></label></p> 
  </fieldset>

  <p>Do you like economy your time?: </p>
  <p><label> yes <input type="radio" name="time" value="yes" checked></label> <label> no <input type="radio" name="time" value="no"></label></p>


  <p>What tool you use to economy your time? </p>
  <p>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="calendar" checked> Calendar </label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="hronometraj" disabled> timekeeping </label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="svoiNarabotki" > achievements </label>
  </p>

  <p>how many hours do you sleep per day?</p>
  <p> 
    <!-- <select  name="sleep" id="sleepTime"   multiple>  -->
    <select  name="sleep" id="sleepTime" size="3" multiple>
      <option value="1" >5</option>
      <option value="2" >6</option>
      <option value="3">7</option>
      <option value="eight" selected>8</option>
      <option value="5">9</option>
    </select>
  </p>


  <p><label for="textarea1">Share your result</label></p>
  <p>
    <textarea name="result message" id="textarea1" cols="50" rows="10" placeholder="Enter your message here..." >
    </textarea>
  </p>
<textarea name="result message" id="textarea" cols="50" rows="10" placeholder="Enter your message here..." >
    </textarea>
<p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit_btn" value="Send">
    <input type="reset" name="reset" value="reset">
  </p>

</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Этот отступ - пробелы между открывающим и закрывающим тэгами `textarea` в Вашем html.

```html
<textarea name="result message" id="textarea1" cols="50" rows="10"
  placeholder="Enter your message here..."></textarea>
```

Comment: Какие-то мы сегодня синхронные)))

Comment: @Qwertiy Синхронно ответили, проголосовали друг за друга и дальше пошли.

Comment: Я набрал 200 баллов этим голосом - ура! :)

Comment: @Qwertiy Мои поздравления!

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67037/discussion-on-answer-by-igor----share-your-result).

Comment: Спасибо Люди Добрые! все получилось)))

Answer (score 2):

У тебя пробелы в разметке и они попадают в поле ввода. Удали их.

```html
<h3>Это вариант с пробелами - как у тебя</h3>
<p>
    <textarea cols="50" rows="3" placeholder="Enter your message here..." >
    </textarea>
</p>

<h3>А это - без пробелов</h3>
<p>
    <textarea name="result message" id="textarea1" cols="50" rows="3" placeholder="Enter your message here..." ></textarea>
</p>
```